# How filter out content from html element with the same name

Tags: puppeteer

HTML Code:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Position</th>
   <th>City &amp; Province</th>
   <th>Country</th>
   <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>...</tr>

  <tr>...</tr>

  <tr valign="top"><td>content1</td></tr>

  <tr>...</tr>

  <tr>...</tr>

  <tr valign="top"><td>content2</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to filter an array of 'tr' elements and only access the content that falls under the 'tr' element that has a 'valign' attribute, I want all the other  elements to be ignored.

Puppeteer code:

```
const options = await page.$$eval('table tbody tr', (trArray) =>
  trArray.map((tr) => tr.valign)
);

//current results = ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
//expected results = content1,content2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get only needed `tr` by selector `'table tbody tr[valign]'`. To get the content, try `tr.innerText`:

```js
const options = await page.$$eval('table tbody tr[valign]', (trArray) =>
  trArray.map((tr) => tr.innerText)
);
```